# Have a value selected by default on a select (AngularJS 2.0)

Tags: html, angular

In the code that I put below I have a select with a list of people and
wanted to know how I could make it so that for example the one named
Agustin is marked by default.

```
<md-select placeholder="people" class="full-width" formControlName="people" required>
  <md-option *ngFor="let per of people" [value]="per.id">{{ per.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```